# Create regex for email id validation with condition

Tags: java, regex

I have tried to validate the below condition with regex for email id.
The email id should be alphanumeric, can include _ and . symbol. But the email id should not be only numeric like 1234@gmail.com.

```
public boolean validateEmail(String input){
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z.]+");
    Matcher idMatcher = regex.matcher(input);
    return idMatcher.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this regex pattern

```
^(?!.[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z.]+
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be

```
[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_.]+[@]+[A-Za-z]+.[A-Za-z]
```